# How can I declare a non-writable array in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, persistence, readonly

Currently, my code resembles this:

```
private static readonly int[] INTARRAY = {1, 2, 3};
```

This prevents me from assigning to `INTARRAY` to a new instance of `int[]` outside of the static constructor, but it still allows me to assign to the individual `int` elements.
For example:

```
INTARRAY[1] = 5;
```

How can I make this array completely read-only? This is an array of value-types, and is assigned with an array initializer in the declaration. How can I make these initial values persist indefinitely?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's an array, you can't. But if you're willing for it to be an `IList<int>`, you can do:

```
private static readonly IList<int> INTARRAY = new List<int> {1, 2, 3}.AsReadOnly();
```

Comment: Also note that if you need it as an array, you just use `.ToArray()` on the list. Also, the `ReadonlyCollection` type might be useful, rather than `List`, depending on what youre using it for.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, there is no builtin c# construct that provides this feature for arrays. Best solution is to use a List instead if it conforms with your business needs

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely set on using an array, you could write a simple wrapper class around the array with a read-only [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx) accessing the elements.